# Where to download OpenVPN CLIENT for Windows?

Tags: openvpn

Where to download OpenVPN CLIENT for Windows?

Currently they have only server on page https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/downloads.html

Where is the client?

**UPDATE**

Okay, below is "research".

I go to download page and download 64 bit installer:

[image]

Then I start the installer

[image]

[image]

As you see, there is no "CLIENT" word in windows title.

Note, that on their help page they have this word in the guide:

[image]

Picture is here: https://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/docs/admin-guides-sp-859543150/howto-connect-client-configuration/395-how-to-install-the-openvpn-client-on-windows.html

Of course, this can have two explanations: either we are downloading incorrect program (server, not client) or they have changed setup title while documentation contains old pictures.

Will continue and see.

Choosing components:

[image]

Install location:

[image]

Not starting GUI immediately:

[image]

But starting it from menu:

[image]

Here it is:

[image]

As you see, no any items to connect to any server found. Only `Settings` present. No any appropriate setting inside (server IP, username, password etc).

Comment: This does not seem well researched.

Comment: @Ramhound see research above please

Comment: You have to add a VPN server... OpenVPN is just a client, not an actual VPN. Try this guide by VPNBook: [Set Up OpenVPN on Windows 10](http://www.vpnbook.com/howto/setup-openvpn-on-windows10)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the Downloads on the page you linked. I have circled them in red just in case you can still not see them.

[image: OpenVPN Client]

Comment: I downloaded these but didn't find any client functionality there

Comment: See screenshots above please.